# Through[] For Association

Tags: functions, associations

I have an association

```
<| a->f, b->g |>
```

where `f` and `g` are pure functions. Is there a nice way to apply arguments to both `f` and `g`? E.g.

```
<| a->f, b->g |>[x] --> <| a->f[x], b->g[x] |>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) provided in a comment we can [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) a [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) that applies its argument to a specific expression, e.g. `x`:

```
#[x] & /@ <|a -> f, b -> g|>
```

> ```
> <|a -> f[x], b -> g[x]|>
> ```

Comment: Still, as did OP, I'd expect Through to work (does it?)

Comment: @LLlAMnYP you mean like `Through[<|a -> f, b -> g|>[x]]` ?  No, it does not; the body evaluates to `Missing["KeyAbsent", x]`.  `Through[Unevaluated[<|a -> f, b -> g|>[x]]]` gives `Association[(a -> f)[x], (b -> g)[x]]` but I don't find that helpful.  `With[{asc = <|a -> f, b -> g|>}, Through[Unevaluated[asc[x]]]]` just kicks back `Through[Unevaluated[<|a -> f, b -> g|>[x]]]`.

Comment: Thanks, I do not mind a non cw answer next time :)